# Assign for all post of a post type a specific single-post template

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, templates, single

I have created for my custom post type `computer-hardware` a template `single-Computer-Hardware.php`, with the following header:

```
/* 
 * Template Name: Computer-Hardware Post Template 
 * Template Post Type: Computer-Hardware 
 */
```

However, wordpress automatically assigns me on my post-attributes the default template:

[image]

I have around 120 posts within this post type and would like to use for all of the the `Template` with the name `Computer-Hardware Post Template`.

Any suggestions how to automatically assign this to existing and posts that will be created?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: If your post type is `computer-hardware`, then the template should be `single-computer-hardware.php`, without capitals and without a template header. Post type slugs can't contain capital letters.

Comment: And your post type will use this properly named template without you assigning it in the Post Attributes. This _is_ the default template.